# Apple website push: Signature verification of push package failed

Tags: php, openssl, apple-push-notifications

Following the [Apple Website Push Notification guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/PushNotifications/PushNotifications.html), I'm getting a post-back to `/endpoint/v1/log` with the following error: `Signature verification of push package failed.`

However, when I download and verify manually using

```
curl -O $endpoint/push/v1/pushPackages/x/y
unzip y
openssl smime -verify -in signature -inform der -content manifest.json -noverify
```

I get `Verification successful`.

The certificate is correctly added under the Apple Developer console, and generation of the ZIP is pretty straight-forward:

```
$z = new ZipArchive();
$z->open($tmp, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
$manifest = [];
$data = json_encode([
    'websiteName' => $name,
    'websitePushId' => $pushId,
    'allowedDomains' => $domains,
    'webServiceURL' => "$endpoint/push"
]);
$manifest['website.json'] = sha1($data);
$z->addFromString('website.json', $data);
$data = file_get_contents('static/favicon.png');
foreach (['16x16','16x16@2x','32x32','32x32@2x','128x128','128x128@2x'] as $f) {
    $f = 'icon.iconset/icon_'.$f.'.png';
    $manifest[$f] = sha1($data);
    $z->addFromString($f, $data);
}
file_put_contents('/tmp/manifest.json', json_encode($manifest));
$z->addFile('/tmp/manifest.json','manifest.json');
$pem = file_get_contents('etc/aweb.pem');
$cert = openssl_x509_read($pem);
$pk = openssl_pkey_get_private($pem, 'developer');
openssl_pkcs7_sign(
    '/tmp/manifest.json', '/tmp/signature',
    $cert, $pk, array(), PKCS7_BINARY | PKCS7_DETACHED
);
// PEM to DER
$pem = file_get_contents('/tmp/signature');
preg_match('~Content-Disposition:[^\n]+\s*?([A-Za-z0-9+=/\r\n]+)\s*?-----~', $pem, $matches);
$data = base64_decode($matches[1]);
$z->addFromString('signature', $data);
$z->close();
```

Note the use of `-noverify` because, despite attempts, I cannot get the certificate chain setup right:

```
curl -L https://www.apple.com/appleca/AppleIncRootCertificate.cer | openssl x509 -inform der > certs.pem
curl -L http://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer | openssl x509 -inform der >> certs.pem
openssl smime -verify -in signature -inform der -content manifest.json -CAfile certs.pem
```

yields

```
Verification failure
140184513181352:error:21075075:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_verify:certificate verify error:pk7_smime.c:342:Verify error:unsupported certificate purpose
```

An additional aside: I found that the documentation is *incredibly* unclear on whether the ZIP file should contain a root directory (and if so, what it should be named). After many hours of `Missing files` errors, I finally figured the ZIP should *not* contain a root directory.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to track down the problem: the (2nd) pushId parameter to window.safari.pushNotification.requestPermission contained a typo and mismatched the websitePushId in manifest.json.

Conclusion: incredibly misleading error reporting on Safari's part ;).